# Append to file using golang where file is on a NFS attached volume

Tags: go, nfs

As part of a large file upload feature.

We're using the following to write a 'chunk' of bytes to a file at 'path'. This works fine on local filesystems. Each chunk is correctly written at 'offset'.

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
n, err := f.WriteAt(bytes, offset)
```

On NFS attached storage however the bytes are written at the beginning of the file and not at the requested 'offset'.

Even though it doesn't appear that the process will be able to obtain a lock on the file over NFS. Is there a technique of workaround we could follow to append to a file at 'offset'?

Comment: Why are you using `O_APPEND` if you want to write at a specific offset? `O_APPEND` means that the offset is set to the the current end of the file just before any `write`, while `WriteAt` uses `pwrite` (which may be implemented as an `lseek` + `write`) to write at a specific offset. There's a logical conflict here that is resolved differently depending on the system.

Comment: Thank you for this comment Jim. I'll experiment with different modes.

Comment: Ok! You are right Jim. Feel free to submit an answer which I can select.

Comment: I'm able to correctly write at 'offset' when using: fd, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY, 0660)